# Webpack build working on local but fails on server

Tags: javascript, nginx, webpack

I am trying to deploy an app that works on local but when I put it on the server I get this error that refers to a filter function on an array. Indicating that the compile ES5 JS is broken somehow.

I use the webpack build command and the output works on my local but when I am putting it on the server I get this on the browser:

```
`TypeError: s.filter is not a function    vendor.bundle.9a44edfc.js:2:131513`
```

I don't understand why it would work on my local and not on the server, is the same node, npm and yarn version on both.

I run this command for build

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.babel.js",
"dev": "webpack serve --env mode=dev --env isDevServer --env NODE_ENV=local --config webpack/webpack.config.babel.js"
```

Comment: I assume `isProd` is different on your local computer vs on the server?

Comment: On the server I do not run webpack, I use the webpack to build the code. I have tested the build on my computer and it works but when I put it on the server it does not

Comment: Did you try to not use relative but absolute paths on the production server with `rootDir`?

Comment: Actually it turned out to be the call to my api on express, I was making a call with axios to `await axios('api/names')` instead of `await axios('/api/names')`, was missing the `/` at the beginning and on my computer with nginx 15 no problem but on the server with nginx 14 it would not get the data

Answer (score 0):

It had nothing to do with webpack, I was getting some data by requesting a route to my express server and I used:

```
axios('api/projects')
```

Instead of

```
axios('/api/projects')
```

And just for that it failed to get the data, the funny thing is that on my computer I am using nginx 15 on mac, and on the server I am using nginx 14 with Ubuntu and on my computer it did not failed.

Comment: Why am I having a hard time seeing the difference between these two? They look exactly the same to me.